# Django extending model passing parameter to parent class

Tags: django, django-models

I have models with slug fields that can be translated and in every model i am writing the same code for doing some operations as:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for lang_code, lang_verbose in settings.LANGUAGES:
           if hasattr(self, 'slug_%s' % lang_code) and hasattr(self, 'name_%s' % lang_code):
                trans = getattr(self, 'name_%s' % lang_code, u"")
                if not trans:
                    trans = self.name_en 
                setattr(self, 'slug_%s' % lang_code, slugify(trans))
         super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I am trying to get rid of the same code on those models. I think of using a parent class that is abstract and inherits from models.Model. And i wrote:

```
class ModelSluggable(models.Model):
    #I also need to pass the fromField parameter to the parent class from child
    def __init__(self, fromField): 
        super(SlugWithTrans,self).__init__(fromField)   

    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False, max_length=200, db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for lang_code, lang_verbose in settings.LANGUAGES:
           if hasattr(self, 'slug_%s' % lang_code) and hasattr(self, 'name_%s' % lang_code):
                trans = getattr(self, 'name_%s' % lang_code, u"")
                if not trans:
                    trans = self.name_en 
                setattr(self, 'slug_%s' % lang_code, slugify(trans))
        super(SlugWithTrans, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is this the proper way?

Comment: seems alright to use abstract, but why the __init__ craziness?

Comment: i want to pass an extra parameter to parent class, is there a way to pass it without using init?